# Retrofit How To Parse Without Object Name Only Array?

Tags: android, retrofit

```
    [
  {
    "school_id": "1",
    "name": "Air University"
  },
  {
    "school_id": "2",
    "name": "Alabama A&M University"
  },
  {
    "school_id": "3",
    "name": "Alabama State University"
  },
  {
    "school_id": "4",
    "name": "Amridge University"
  },
  {
    "school_id": "5",
    "name": "Athens State University"
  },
  {
    "school_id": "6",
    "name": "Auburn University"
  }
]
```

How can parse that type response in retrofit 1.9 give me some hint?

Comment: What you have try ?

Comment: Questions seeking help must include *the desired behavior*, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please add more details in question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am assuming your api responds with an array of objects and you want to get a callback for that. You can do it as,

```
@GET('your url')
void getSchools(Callback<ArrayList<School>> callback);
```

where the school class is,

```
public class School {
    String schoolId;
    String name;
}
```